# Prolog: Given a Matrix create the transpose

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to learn how to use Prolog.

I have a matrix and I should make the transpose of this matrix.

I have done in this way:

```
transpose_matrix([], []).
transpose_matrix(Matrix, New_Matrix):-
    length(Matrix, Num_Rows),
    nth0(0, Matrix, First_Row),
    length(First_Row, Num_Cols),
    Num_Rows == Num_Cols,
    transpose_matrix(Matrix, Num_Rows, 0, 0, New_Matrix).

transpose_matrix(Matrix, Num_Rows, Row, Col, [[Element|Rest]|Rest1]):-
    Row < Num_Rows,
    nth0(Row,Matrix,Current_Row),
    nth0(Col,Current_Row,Element),
    Row1 is Row + 1,
    transpose_matrix(Matrix, Num_Rows, Row1, Col, [Rest|Rest1]).

transpose_matrix(Matrix, Num_Rows, Row, Col, [[_Element|_Rest]|Rest1]):-
    Row >= Num_Rows,
    Col1 is Col + 1,
    transpose_matrix(Matrix, Num_Rows, 0, Col1, Rest1).

transpose_matrix(_Matrix, Num_Rows, _Row, Col, _New_Matrix):-
    Col == Num_Rows.
```

In this way when I sum 1 to the Row to choose the correct element, when the Row is equal to the Length so I update the Col and I set the row value equal to 0.

Now this method seems to work, my problem is how the values are printed:

```
transpose_matrix([[6, 3, 2], [8, 1, 4], [3, 5, 9]], New_Matrix).
New_Matrix = [[6, 8, 3, _17602|_17604], [3, 1, 5, _17650|_17652], [2, 4, 9, _17698|_17700]|_17658]
```

How Can I Delete :

> _17602| _17604...._17650|_17652..._17698|_17700]|_17658 ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you out:

1- The transp predicate will take the matrix of any length and will give the Transposed list in MatrixOut.

2- The add_col predicate can save you from the hassle of -1708,... type of values.

```
% transp(MatrixIn,MatrixOut)
transp([],[]).
transp([Row|Rows],Transpose) :-
transp(Rows,RowsT),
add_col(Row,RowsT,Transpose).

% add_col(Col,MatrixIn,MatrixOut)
add_col([],_,[]) :- !.
add_col([X|Col],[],[[X]|Rows]) :- !,
add_col(Col,[],Rows).
add_col([X|Col],[Row|Rows],[NewRow|NewRows]) :-
NewRow = [X|Row],
add_col(Col,Rows,NewRows).
```

**Example**:

```
?-transp([[2,0,1],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]],Out)
Out = [[2, 3, 6], [0, 4, 7], [1, 5, 8]]

?-transp([[6, 3, 2], [8, 1, 4], [3, 5, 9]],Out)
Out = [[6, 8, 3], [3, 1, 5], [2, 4, 9]]

?-transp([[6, 3, 2, 5, 3, 2], [8, 1, 4, 7, 4, 2], [3, 5, 9, 8, 5, 4],[6, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]],Out)
Out = [[6, 8, 3, 6], [3, 1, 5, 4], [2, 4, 9, 5], [5, 7, 8, 7], [3, 4, 5, 8], [2, 2, 4, 9]]
```

**Note:** Solution is from my teacher's Lecture.

Answer (score 2):

A very concise solution is:

```
transpose(Matrix, NewMatrix) :-
    nonvar(Matrix),
    findall(Row, maplist(nth1(_), Matrix, Row), NewMatrix).
```

Here are some examples:

```
?- transpose([[1,2], [3,4]], M).
M = [[1, 3], [2, 4]].

?- transpose([[6,3,2], [8,1,4], [3,5,9]], Matrix).
Matrix = [[6, 8, 3], [3, 1, 5], [2, 4, 9]].

?- transpose([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]], M), maplist(writeln,M).
[1,4,7]
[2,5,8]
[3,6,9]
M = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]].
```

How it works:

- `nth1/3` generate elements (through backtracking).
- `maplist/3` generate rows (through backtracking).
- `findall/3` collect all rows.

Comment: nice solution !